# Looking for the source of a quote about moving to the edge and declaring it the new center

Tags: quote-source

I once read a quote about getting to the top of your field by moving to the edge and declaring it the new center. It wasn't exactly in those words but if I remember correctly is came from someone in an arts or creative field possibly Andy Warhol.

It was concise, nonchalant and pithy in the manner that Andy often answered any question he was asked. I encountered it about 10-15 years ago if that helps. Can anyone identify the source or confirm it was Andy Warhol?

Comment: I believe I saw something like that in this awesome documentary on warhol, maybe the pbs one.

Answer (score 3):

The earliest use of a close match which I can find is Toni Morrison in a 1998 interview with journalist Jana Wendt. When discussing whether or not she is 'in the mainstream' and in reference to the recognition of having been awarded a Nobel prize for Literature in 1993.

> I stood at the border, stood at the edge, and claimed it as central. And yet, the rest of the world moved over to where I was.

The interview can be viewed [here on You Tube](https://youtu.be/WoTELoC8Q0M), with the specific section beginning with Wendt's question at around 25.15